# How to hide referer using JavaScript or jQuery redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect

I cannot get this to work. Can you help me?

I load this page in my browser:

```
http://www.domain.com/in.php?public=1&private=2
```

The following code immediately gets called to reload the page without the private value:

```
window.location = "http://www.domain.com/in.php?public=1";
// I've also tried window.location.href and window.location.replace
```

When the page loads the following code gets called:

```
<?=header("Location: http://www.different-domain.com")?>
```

So as you can see it goes like this:

```
domain.com -> domain.com -> different-domain.com
```

This is the problem:

When I look in the access log for different-domain.com, it shows someone coming from the first page load rather than the redirect. So the log shows the following referer:

```
http://www.domain.com/in.php?public=1&private=2
```

How can I fix the above so the referer will be:

```
http://www.domain.com/in.php?public=1
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should not use the referer, as its unreliable, this whole approach looks like an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Do you know how I can hide the referer? Unfortunately this is something I must do.

Comment: redirect to another domain with any referer you want? = use curl

Answer (score -2):

Use a hidden post form to submit values, that may help you.

some thing like

```
<form method='post' action='your location' style='display:none;'> 
<input type='text' value='1' name='public'> 
<input type='text' value='2' name='private'> 
</form>
```

submit this form to your location where you want.